# How to get my code working?

Tags: javascript, android, android-canvas, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to save canvas drawing to my android phone storage when clicked on a div.
I am using phoneGap build.I have tried using [Canvas2ImagePlugin](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin) .
I modified the config.xml file and added this line of code

```
<gap:plugin name="org.devgeeks.canvas2imageplugin" version="0.6.0" />
```

and add this to the JavaScript file

```
function saveCanvas(){
      window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
          function(msg){
               console.log(msg);
          },
          function(err){
              console.log(err);
          },
          document.getElementById('canvas')
     );
};

document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', saveCanvas);
```

the canvas has an id of "canvas" and the div has an id of "download".
I didn't get anything when clicked on the div, what's wrong ?!

Comment: You should install it through command line. It will do everything it needs to  by itself https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin#installation
Then you can start implementing it

Comment: @Gorcyn I have already added it through config.xml
and it appear in the phoneGap build that  I have added a Plugin

Comment: Yes, but it does more, like adding the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin/blob/master/plugin.xml